# ajax to post and return html to display in div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, portal

jQuery v 1.9.0

When the page loads I am firing two functions (get_month() & get_todays_events()) and those return the calendar and today's events html.

Sometimes when I refresh the page, it will display the today's events twice and does not display the calendar(month), as seen below.

[image]
**Half the time it works just fine, as seen below:**

[image]

There are no errors in the firebug console. It works fine as a stand-alone app, but when I incorporate it into Jasig's uPortal, it messes up.

Then I tried stripping the html that gets sent back from the ajax posts and I noticed the get_todays_events(); may be the culprit, but I still don't know what it could be.

Is there something in the html that may be tripping things up or should I have a delay on firing that function after the get_month(); fires?

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  function get_month()
  {
    var url_month = jQuery("#days_for_month_url").attr("href");

    var form_data = { ajax : '1' };

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      url: url_month,
      crossDomain: true,
      data: form_data,
      success: function( default_month_msg ) {

        jQuery('#display-month').html(default_month_msg);

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax
    //return false;
  }

  function get_todays_events()
  {
    var url_todays_events = jQuery("#todays_events_url").attr("href");

    var form_data = { ajax : '1' };

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      url: url_todays_events,
      crossDomain: true,
      data: form_data,
      success: function( default_month_msg ) {

        jQuery('#display_todays_events').html(default_month_msg);

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax
    //return false;
  }

  get_month();
  console.log("display calendar");

  get_todays_events();
  console.log("display today's events");

  jQuery(document).on('click', "a.view_events", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var date = jQuery(this).data('date');

    // change if URL changes
    var url_events = jQuery("#events_for_day_url").attr("href");

    var form_data = {
      year : jQuery(this).data('year'),
      month : jQuery(this).data('month'),
      day : jQuery(this).data('day'),
      date : jQuery(this).data('date'),
      ajax : '1'
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      url: url_events,
      data: form_data,
      success: function( msg ) {

        jQuery('#display-events').html(msg);
        jQuery('#display-event_detail').html('');
        jQuery('#display_todays_events').html('');

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax

    return false;

  }); // end on.click view-events

  jQuery(document).on('click', "a.view_event_details", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url_event_detail = jQuery("#event_detail_url").attr("href");

    var form_data = {
      event_id : jQuery(this).data('event_id'),
      ajax : '1'
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      url: url_event_detail,
      data: form_data,
      success: function( msg ) {

        jQuery('#display-event_detail').html(msg);
        jQuery('#display-events').html('');
        jQuery('#display_todays_events').html('');

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax

    return false;

  }); // end on.click view_event_details

  jQuery(document).on('click', "a.month_link", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery('#display-events').html('');

    var url_days_for_month = jQuery("#days_for_month_url").attr("href");

    var form_data = {
      month_url : jQuery(this).data('month_url'),
      ajax : '1'
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      url: url_days_for_month,
      data: form_data,
      success: function( msg ) {

        jQuery('#display-month').html(msg);
        jQuery('#display_todays_events').html('');

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax

    return false;

  }); // end on.click view-month

  jQuery(document).on('click', "a.view_subscriptions", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url_subscription = jQuery("#subscriptions_url").attr("href");

    var form_data = {
      ajax : '1'
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      url: url_subscription,
      data: form_data,
      success: function( msg ) {

        jQuery('#display-subscriptions').html(msg);
        //jQuery('#display-subscriptions').toggle();

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax

    return false;

  }); // end on.click view-subscriptions

  jQuery(document).on('click', "#update_subscriptions", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url_update_subscription = jQuery("#update_subscriptions_url").attr("href");

    var vals = []
    jQuery('input:checkbox[name="calendar[]"]').each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            vals.push(this.value);
        }
    });

    var form_data = {
      ajax : '1',
      calendar: vals,
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      url: url_update_subscription,
      data: form_data,
      success: function( msg ) {

        get_month();
        jQuery('#display-subscriptions-update').html(msg).fadeOut(6000);
        jQuery('#display-subscriptions').html('');
        jQuery('#display-events').html('');
        jQuery('#display_todays_events').html('');

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax

    return false;

  }); // end on.click view-subscriptions

}); // end document ready
```

Here is the html that is returned on success for the get_todays_events() function

```
<h3>Today's Events</h3>


  <p><a href="#" class="view_event_details" data-event_id="68">All About Heroin</a> - 12:30 pm</p>


  <p><a href="#" class="view_event_details" data-event_id="67">African Storyteller - Ekow King</a> - 12:30 pm</p>


  <p><a href="#" class="view_event_details" data-event_id="66">Men&rsquo;s Basketball vs. Columbia-Greene Community College</a> - 6:00 pm</p>
```

UPDATE: checked the net tab in firebug and examined XHR, when using in uPortal, it would fire off two post requests and two get requests. Both POST requests were retuning 0 byte, but the GET requests were returning something. I changed them to GETS, since I wasn't really asking the user to enter data, but click a link that had the data already (that being the date they wanted view events for), so I appended the date value to the URL I was passing into the ajax get request, then it returned it correctly every time.

Comment: you havent given us any of the code in your JS functions. or what is happening on the server side, just what is getting returned. in order for us to help we need these details. Use Fiddler or firebug to see what is actually getting returned from the AJAX call.

Comment: added - forgot to add it originally

Comment: would it be possible to get the full rendered page before these calls are made, i would say that somewhere in your form the wrong url is being placed.

Comment: Its not a form. I am using the ajax to post to a controller method called post_calendar() and post_todays_events(), which returns the appropriate html. It works half the time when using in uPortal, if you're directly on the page it works everytime.

Comment: yes but you are using `jQuery("#events_for_day_url").attr("href")` selector to get the url's for the AJAX, i could only assume that you have a bug somewhere on the controller side returning the wrong URL. like i said use Fiddler or Firebug to catch what is actually being returned to the client

Comment: When I commented out get_todays_events(); it displayed the calendar only, everytime too, so that function might be the problem.

Comment: We need to see the page's html before the calls. Maybe display-month div is defined INSIDE display_todays_events div or vice versa? I assume they should be defined one below the other but maybe you forgot to close the divs correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add to the ajax call parameters async=false (add this to all the ajax calls).

For example:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  url: url_todays_events,
  crossDomain: true,
  data: form_data,
  async:false,
  success: function( default_month_msg ) {

    jQuery('#display_todays_events').html(default_month_msg);

  } // end success

});
```